# any way to destructure a dict in python like es6 in js?

Tags: python, destructuring

If I have a dict like this:

```
 dict1 =  {'version': 0, 'name': 'JSESSIONID', 'value': 'AFCF8A9D8AB9E7B701A4D60EE7D8C475.prdaccountc-108', 'port': None, 'port_specified': False, 'domain': 'signin.ea.com', 'domain_specified': False, 'domain_initial_dot': False, 'path': '/p', 'path_specified': True, 'secure': True, 'expires': None, 'discard': True, 'comment': None, 'comment_url': None, 'rfc2109': False, '_rest': {'HttpOnly': None, 'SameSite': 'None'}}
```

I want to destructure that dict and get it's values like this:

```
version, name, value = dict1
```

instead of doing this:

```
version = dict1["version"]
name = dict1["name"]
value = value["value"]
```

when I tried to do this I got ValueError: too many values to unpack

Answer (score 3):

The `itemgetter` function from the inbuilt library `operator` can be used to achieve something roughly equivalent:

```
from operator import itemgetter

params = {'a': 1, 'b': 2}

a, b = itemgetter('a', 'b')(params)
```

Note that this depends on `a` and `b` matching the names `'a'` and `'b'` being passed to `itemgetter`, so it's not actually achieving what the ES6 operator is as transparently - but it is a fairly similar syntax on the surface.

Answer (score 0):

You could use `dict.values()`,make sure the order is what you want(Python >= 3.6):

```
version, name, value = dict1.values()
```

---

If the length of dict1 is larger than the amount of receiver,Try:

```
version, name, value, *other = dict1.values()
```

Comment: Dict's order is guaranteed only for python>=3.6

Comment: does not work this is my dict: 
<class 'dict'>: {'version': 0, 'name': 'JSESSIONID', 'value': 'AFCF8A9D8AB9E7B701A4D60EE7D8C475.prdaccountc-108', 'port': None, 'port_specified': False, 'domain': 'signin.ea.com', 'domain_specified': False, 'domain_initial_dot': False, 'path': '/p', 'path_specified': True, 'secure': True, 'expires': None, 'discard': True, 'comment': None, 'comment_url': None, 'rfc2109': False, '_rest': {'HttpOnly': None, 'SameSite': 'None'}}

Comment: This is very easy-to-break code, and I wouldn't recommend it - and it also doesn't come close to doing what's actually happening in ES6 object destructuring assignments